# How to use multiple callbacks in JavaScript event callback of CakePHP

Tags: cakephp-1.3

I want to put a loading div when triggering an event function of *JsHelper* of CakePHP. Here is my code:

```
$this->Js->get('#MonthlyProgressProjectId')->event('change',
            $this->Js->get('#MonthlyProgressAddForm')->request(array(
                'action' => 'get_institution'), array(
                'update' => '#institution',
                'dataExpression'=>TRUE, 
                'method'=>'POST',
                'async'=>TRUE,
                'data' => $js->serializeForm(array('isForm' => TRUE, 'inline' => TRUE)))));
```

Here you see, I'm getting the form and then use the `request()` function. But while triggering this function, I want to show a loading div. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Add the loading image where you want it to be. E.g.
`$this->Html->image('loading.gif', array('id'=> 'loader'));`

Add the following to the options array of your request:

```
'before' => $this->Js->get('#loader')->effect('fadeIn', array('buffer' => false));
'complete' => $this->Js->get('#loader')->effect('fadeOut', array('buffer' => false));
```

Now you're almost done. You want `#loader` to be invisible when you first land on the page, so add to your CSS `#loader { display: none; }`.

Now when your event is triggered, the `#loader` will fade in, with your loading image. And when it's done, it will fade out again. And if you want a div around it, just wrap a div around it with an ID, and perform the actions on that.

Comment: I'd tried this. But the problem is, the request method does not trigger when the event occur. Here the code which is generated..

`$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#loader").bind("change", function (event){
        $.ajax({
            async:true,
            beforeSend:function (XMLHttpRequest)  $("#loader").show();}, data:$("#loader").closest("form").serialize(), dataType:"html", success:function (data, textStatus) {$("#MonthlyProgressInstitutionId").html(data);}, type:"POST", url:"\/cakebake\/monthly_progresses\/get_institution"});
return false;});`

Comment: I have the same problem.In my case the ajax request stops when i add before and complete options.